# how to iterate html elements and swap their values

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I wanted swap the element values, on UP/Down button clicks. For example in the below html snippet, I have two sets Guidance and Communication, on UP/Down button click, all the values of Guidance set(checkbox, textbox values) has to swapped with Communication values.  I am planning to write up a simple javascript swap function, could you help me write it using simple and clean javascript code?

JS:

```
var from_list = getElementsByClassName("from");
var to_list = getElementsByClassName("to");
for (var i = 0; i < from_list.length; i++) {
    //swap logic
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Guidance :</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="guidance" name="guidlobs" value="g1">Box1</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="guidance" name="guidlobs" value="g2">Box2</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="guidance" name="guidlobs" value="g3">Box3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Guid Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="guidance" name="guidance_name" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Guid URL :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="guidance" name="guidance_url" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="DN" onclick="swap('guidance','communication')" />
        </td>
        <td>Guid Description:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="guidance" name="guidance_desc" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Communication :</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="commlobs" value="c1">Box1</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="commlobs" value="c2">Box2</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="commlobs" value="c3">Box3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="UP" onclick="swap('communication','guidance')" />
        </td>
        <td>Communication Name :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="communication" name="communication_name" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Communication URL:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="communication" name="communication_url" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="DN" onclick="swap('communication','training')" />
        </td>
        <td>Communication Description :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="communication" name="communication_desc" style="width:500px;" value="" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't see any element with `form` or `to`classes.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki They are hidden in the HTML: `swap('guidance','communication')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. See if that helps you:

```
window.swap = function(fromClass, toClass) {
  var from_list= document.getElementsByClassName(fromClass);
  var to_list = document.getElementsByClassName(toClass);

  var tmp;
  for(var i = 0; i < from_list.length; i++) {
      //swap logic      
      if (from_list[i].type == "checkbox") {
          tmp = from_list[i].checked;
          from_list[i].checked = to_list[i].checked;
          to_list[i].checked = tmp;      
      } else {
        tmp = from_list[i].value;
        from_list[i].value = to_list[i].value;
        to_list[i].value = tmp;
      }
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1cgeyyb0/1/

Comment: Hi Lucas, text box values gets swaped with your logic but not the checkbox items(check/uncheck). Thanks.

Comment: So you want to swap the "state" and not the actual value of the checkbox? Or you want both?

Comment: Lucas, I wanted to swap only the state.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, it works!!